# get Arabic folders names from zip archive using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, zip

I have a zip archive containing folders and files which have Arabic titles (names) like:

```
مجلد جديد، ملف...
```

I'm trying to extract these folders using PHP.

The problem is: after uploading this file and extract it, the names are going into miss like:

```
مجلد جديد => ê¤é§ ¤§ï§
```

I'm using this piece of code to extract:

```
$saved_file_location = $target . $filename;

if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target . $filename)) {
    openZip($saved_file_location);
}

function openZip($file_to_open) {
    global $target;
    global $unique_folder;
            global $changed;
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($file_to_open);
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($target . $unique_folder);
            $zip->close();

            unlink($file_to_open); #deletes the zip file. We no longer need it.
                            $changed = true;
        } else {
            die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the function `openZip` come from?

Comment: `function openZip($file_to_open) {
  global $target;
  global $unique_folder;
                global $changed;
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $x = $zip->open($file_to_open);
   if ($x === true) {
    $zip->extractTo($target . $unique_folder);
    $zip->close();

    unlink($file_to_open); #deletes the zip file. We no longer need it.
                                $changed = true;
   } else {
    die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
   }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Zip files do not know about the encoding of file names. You have to guess the encoding of the file names and convert them to the encoding used by your file system.

Comment: I know the encoding... I'm sure it's utf-8... how to convert them into my working encoding which is also utf-8... but after extraction the names became in mess... how to correct them???